# npm install electron -g -> unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, electron

[The Situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yZLq.png)
I'm trying to install Electron globally on my computer using the following command:

```
npm install electron -g
```

However, I keep encountering this error:

```
unable to verify the first certificate
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'E:\\ProgramLang\\NVM\\v20.6.1\\node_modules\\electron\\node_modules\\@szmarczak',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'E:\ProgramLang\NVM\v20.6.1\node_modules\electron\node_modules\@szmarczak\http-timer'] {
...
npm ERR! RequestError: unable to verify the first certificate
...
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Yu\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-16T11_15_26_872Z-debug-0.log
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Answers in both English and Chinese are welcome.

Additionally, I noticed that some users encountered the `unable to verify the first certificate` error when installing **express**. However, I can install **express** globally without any issues using `npm install express -g`. This seems to be specific to **electron** in my case.

I've already tried running PowerShell as an administrator and setting the **NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED** environment variable to 0, but neither approach has resolved the problem.

I've also tried using the Taobao registry with the --strict-ssl=false flag, but the issue persists.
like this:

```
npm install electron -g --registry=https://registry.npm.taobao.org --strict-ssl=false
```

After facing issues with **npm**, I decided to switch to **yarn**. Here's the log of my operations:

```
PS C:\Users\Yu> yarn global add electron
yarn global v1.22.19
warning You don't appear to have an internet connection. Try the --offline flag to use the cache for registry queries.
warning package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
error C:\Users\Yu\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\electron: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\Yu\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\electron
Output:
RequestError: unable to verify the first certificate
...
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
PS C:\Users\Yu>
```

Comment: Have you looked into this? https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/26910 , if does not work only as a last resort try `npm config set strict-ssl false` but be sure to turn it on after installing.

Comment: Thank you.But I have tried `npm config set strict-ssl false`.Still it doesn't work.

But. When I try the method 2 in the github issue.(**use cnpm**). I **succeed**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have you looked into this? [github.com/electron/electron/issues/26910](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/26910) , if does not work only as a last resort try npm config set strict-ssl false but be sure to turn it on after installing. – **v1shva**

I solved the problem.So use cnpm may help.
But I didn't succeed some days ago when I try this method.
So if somebody is faced with the problem.You can try it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).